# Swift setting a custom font color for a SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, swift, colors, sprite-kit

I'm trying to set a custom color to a SKLabelNode.

Here is my code:

```
coinLabel.fontName = "Bebas"
    coinLabel.fontSize = 30
    coinLabel.fontColor = SKColor(red: 233, green: 157, blue: 20, alpha: 1)
    coinLabel.text = " \(UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "COINSCORE"))"
    coinLabel.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 3.1, y: self.frame.height / 2.23)
    coinLabel.zPosition = 1.1
    self.addChild(coinLabel)
```

However this is not working and shows the previous color I set which was simply by doing:

```
coinLabel.fontColor = .black
```

Comment: paste more code - what method the code is in and when does it run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use something like

```
SKColor(red: 233/255, green: 157/255, blue: 20/255, alpha: 1)
```

because red, green and blue is a value between 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 1):

If your like me and can never remember or want to type in ALL those 255's ;). You can extend SKColor, so that you can enter the rgb's just using the values.

```
extension SKColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255.0, green: g/255.0, blue: b/255.0, alpha:a)
    }

    convenience init(_ r: CGFloat, _ g: CGFloat, _ b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255.0, green: g/255.0, blue: b/255.0, alpha:1)
    }
}
```

now you can just type

```
coinLabel.fontColor = SKColor(red: 233, green: 157, blue: 20, alpha: 1)
```